# Significance of the [Net.SecurityProtocolType] enumeration constants?

Tags: powershell, enums

Why does the SecurityProtocolType enum have the following constants:

| Enum Value | Enumeration Constant |
| --- | --- |
| Ssl3 | 48 |
| Tls | 192 |
| Tls11 | 768 |
| Tls12 | 3072 |
| Tls13 | 12288 |

I notice that each integer is 4 times the previous one, but would integer values of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 not suffice to allow for bitwise operations?



*I have omitted the 'SystemDefault' value (0) because presumably this is mutually exclusive from the others?

Comment: Did you check [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=net-5.0#remarks)

Comment: @PowerCat I did indeed

Comment: What's provoking the question? (My point is that the values are what they are - why does it matter what bits are set in the value, and what would you do with the answer if you got one? Or are you asking because you are just curious?)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I feel that there probably is a specific reason for it. The constants take up more storage space and are slightly slower to operate on than the low powers of 2. Only by tiny, tiny fractions for modern computers, but why wouldn't you make a solution as simple as possible if you have the ability to? A (team of) developer specified the integers and I feel that they must have chosen them for a reason

Comment: What difference would it make if you found out the reason why? (Related: [If you don’t know what you’re going to do with the answer to a question, then there’s not much point in making others work hard to answer it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130417-00/?p=4633))

Comment: The difference is - then I would fully understand the SecurityProtocolType constants rather than accepting a limitation. I am surprised that I am being asked to justify a quest for knowledge in this environment.

Comment: Regarding your previous comments: "The constants take up more storage space": This is not really true, as in all likelihood the values are bits in a 32-bit unsigned integer (if this is the case, only a single 32-bit unsigned would be used and would not take up more storage space). "Slightly slower to operate on than low powers of 2": This would also be false, as handling bitmap values are single operations. As far as needing to justify a quest for knowledge: A quest for knowledge is fine, but you can see the point in the link I posted...What is the purpose? What limitation are you accepting?

Comment: The purpose is for knowledge. To augment my own knowledge, and also to broaden the online powershell corpus because as far as I have been able to ascertain the answer to this question does not exist online. 

The limitation would be accepting that industry-leading developers stuck arbitrary numbers in to the Net.SecurityProtocolType enum. Why would they have done that? 

It's more likely that there is a reasoning behind the constants, but I just don't know it yet.

Comment: What if the values are entirely arbitrary? What difference would it make?

Comment: Ha we are starting to go round in circles! I will post the answer if I manage to find it (if there is one!)

Comment: I appreciate the curiosity, but you still haven't answered what practical, real-world difference it would make if you found an answer?